# Working with big text files

Tags: c++, file, text-files

I have a file in following format:

```
[1]
Parameter1=Value1
.
.
.
End
[2]
.
.
```

The number between brackets presents id of the entity. There're around 4500 entites. I need to parse through all entites and pick the ones matching my parameters and values. Size of file is around 20mb. My first approach was to reading file line by line and storing them in a struct array like:

```
struct Component{
    std::string parameter;
    std::string value;
};
struct Entity{
    std::string id;
    std::list<Component> components;
};
std::list<Entity> g_entities;
```

But this approach took enormous amount of memory and was very slow. I've also tried storing only the ones that match my parameters/values. But that also was really slow and took quite some memory. Ideally i would like to store all data in memory so that i won't have to load the file everytime i need to filter my parameters/values if it's possible with reasonable amount of memory usage.

Edit 1:
I read file line by line:

```
            std::ifstream readTemp(filePath);
            std::stringstream dataStream;
            dataStream << readTemp.rdbuf();
            readTemp.close();

            while (std::getline(dataStream, line)){
                    if (line.find('[') != std::string::npos){
                        // Create Entity
                        Entity entity;

                        // Set entity id
                        entity.id = line.substr(line.find('[') + 1, line.find(']') - 1);

                        // Read all lines until EnumEnd=0
                        while (1){
                            std::getline(dataStream, line);
                            // Break loop if end of entity
                            if (line.find("EnumEnd=0") != std::string::npos){
                                if (CheckMatch(entity))
                                    entities.push_back(entity);
                                entity.components.clear();
                                break;
                            }


                            Component comp;
                            int pos_eq = line.find('='); 
                            comp.parameterId = line.substr(0, pos_eq);
                            comp.value = line.substr(pos_eq + 1);

                            entity.components.push_back(comp);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The only thing I would change from what you show us, is to use a vector of [maps](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) ([unordered maps](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if available), alternatively a map of maps if the section names can be anything else than numbers.

Comment: As for the slow loading, it might be because of how you parse the file. Or because you don't know how many entries are needed in each vector, so they have to be reallocated multiple times. Or something else completely. The file may be big for a text-file, but not very big more generally.

Comment: Maybe we would get ideas what to change from what you do not show us... Like the read / parse code. Apart from that, you could also consider to read the whole file without parsing to memory (20MB) and then parse on demand. Deluxe version: Remember the indices of where entities start. Then do some indirect sorting or something. Depends on what you eventually need.

Comment: can you post the code you used to parse the file? the slowness/memory consumption might be related to problems with the parser (memory leaks, non optimized flow, etc..)

Comment: The problem here is the `vector`, which will relocate an enormous amount of data in insertion. Using a `list` should already show a big improvement.

Comment: Added file parse code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PS: After your edit. and Comment concerning memory consumption**

```
500MB / 20MB = 25.
```

If each line is 25 chars long, the memory consumption looks ok.

OK you could use a look-up table for mapping parameter-names to numbers.
If the names-set is small, this will save the consumption up to 2 times.

Your data structure could look like this:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, std::string> > my_ini_file_data;
std::map<std::string, int> param_to_idx;
```

(provided the parameter names within sections (entities as you call it) are not unique)

Putting the data is:

```
std::string param = "Param";
std::string value = "Val";
int entity_id = 0;
if ( param_to_idx.find(param) == param_to_idx.end() )
  param_to_idx[param] = param_to_idx.size();
my_ini_file_data[entity_id][ param_to_idx[param] ] = value;
```

getting the data is:

```
    value = my_ini_file_data[entity_id][ param_to_idx[param] ];
```

If the values-set is also considerably smaller than the number of entries,
you could even map values to numbers:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int> > my_ini_file_data;
std::map<std::string, int> param_to_idx;
std::map<std::string, int> value_to_idx;
std::map<int, std::string> idx_to_value;
```

Putting the data is:

```
std::string param = "Param";
std::string value = "Val";
int entity_id = 0;
if ( param_to_idx.find(param) == param_to_idx.end() )
      param_to_idx[param] = param_to_idx.size();
if ( value_to_idx.find(value) == value_to_idx.end() )
{  
      int idx = value_to_idx.size();
      value_to_idx[value] = idx;
      idx_to_value[idx] = value;
}

my_ini_file_data[entity_id][ param_to_idx[param] ] = value_to_idx[value];
```

getting the data is:

```
value = idx_to_value[my_ini_file_data[entity_id][ param_to_idx[param] ] ];
```

Hope, this helps.

**Initial answer**

Concerning memory, I wouldn't care unless you have a kind of embedded system with very small memory.

Concerning the speed, I could give you some suggestions:

Find out, what is the bottleneck.

1. Use std::list! Using std::vector you re-initialize the memory each time the vector grows. If for some reason you need a vector at the end, create the vector reserving the requires number of entries, which you'll get by calling list::size()
2. Write a while loop, there you only call getline. If this alone is
   already slow, read the entire block at once, create a reader-stream
   out of the char* block and read line by line from the stream.
3. If the speed of the simple reading is OK, optimize your parsing code. You
   can reduce the number of find-calls by storing the position. e.g.

   ```
   int pos_begin = line.find('[]');
   if (pos_begin != std::string::npos){
       int pos_end = line.find(']');
       if (pos_end != std::string::npos){
           entity.id = line.substr(pos_begin + 1, pos_begin - 1);

           // Read all lines until EnumEnd=0
           while (1){
               std::getline(readTemp, line);
               // Break loop if end of entity
               if (line.find("EnumEnd=0") != std::string::npos){
                   if (CheckMatch(entity))
                       entities.push_back(entity);
                   break;
               }


               Component comp;
               int pos_eq = line.find('=');

               comp.parameter= line.substr(0, pos_eq);
               comp.value = line.substr(pos_eq + 1);

               entity.components.push_back(comp);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   4. Depending on how big your entities are, check if CheckMatch is slow. The smaller the entities, the slower the code - in this case.

Comment: Thanks edited some of the code wtih points you made. Kind of stuck with unordered_map. Also Entity id's are always number.

Comment: @AcarX: unordered_map? I have not mentioned sth. like this. Converting std::vector to std::list and probably reading with bigger blocks, should give the improvement.

Comment: Updated code. I've closed application after reaching 500mb memory usage. What am i doing wrong ? CheckMatch() is currently empty.

Comment: Vectors won't reallocate every time you add to them. They tend to just double their capacity as appropriate, so at most, you're wasting half the vector (but gaining back because you don't need to store pointers to nodes like `list` does). See [example](http://goo.gl/H04tb7).

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Memory usage is going insane after couple of seconds. http://i.imgur.com/tpGRiJv.png

Comment: I'm ashamed to say this but apparently there was a missing EndEnum=0 somewhere which was resulting in infinite loop and infinite memory usage.  Fixing that solved memory usage problem. But i learned how to store it properly. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder, why do you need EnumEnd=0 at all to complete the section.  Actually, you don't have to store the entity-data temporarily or care about to which entity the parameters belong. Just verify that the entity number is valid (e.g. there are empty  or comment lines at the beginning) and put them all in your map using []-op: `my_data[entity_id][param_name] = value;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use less memory by [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) your params and values, so as not to store multiple copies of them.

You could have a map of strings to unique numeric IDs, that you create when loading the file, and then just use the IDs when querying your data structure. At the expense of possibly slower parsing initially, working with these structures afterwards should be faster, as you'd only be matching 32-bit integers rather than comparing strings.

Sketchy proof of concept for storing each string once:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int string_id(const string& s) {
  static unordered_map<string, int> m;
  static int id = 0;

  auto it = m.find(s);
  if (it == m.end()) {
    m[s] = ++id;
    return id;
  } else {
    return it->second;
  }
}

int main() {
  // prints 1 2 2 1
  cout << string_id("hello") << " ";
  cout << string_id("world") << " "; 
  cout << string_id("world") << " ";
  cout << string_id("hello") << endl; 
}
```

The `unordered_map` will end up storing each string once, so you're set for memory. Depending on your matching function, you can define

```
struct Component {
    int parameter;
    int value;
};
```

and then your matching can be something like `myComponent.parameter == string_id("some_key")` or even `myComponent.parameter == some_stored_string_id`. If you want your strings back, you'll need a reverse mapping as well.

Comment: Good potential savings there - particularly for the params which are likely highly repetitive.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to follow that route but still my parsing issue continues. I feel like there's a big problem with my parse code.

Comment: Edited some of the code. I get the idea with string interning but quite confused with how to use it. I figured that when i use unmappedObject.insert({id, string}) it's inserting the string. But how do i know same string isnt in unmapped object already ? Also how do i know which id points to which string ?

Comment: Application is still reaching 500mb memory usage in 30 seconds. I feel like i'm leaking memory ?